# .NET Core 3.1 and Angular 6 SignalR setup connects but not receiving messages

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr

I am experiencing some issues with configuring my project to use SignalR. The connection gets established from my Client to the Hub, and I can see my logs in Seq indicating that the messages are being sent, but I am not receiving any messages in the Client. I have struggled with this for a long time, and I am not sure what exactly I have done wrong?

I have my Hub class:

```
public class SourceControlHub : Hub
{

}
```

In Startup I add signalR service:

```
services.AddSignalR();
```

And map the hub:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
    endpoints.MapSwagger();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapHub<SourceControlHub>("/sourceControlHub");
});
```

I send my message like this:

```
await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("SendProgressReportMessage", snapshotId, uploadCount, uploaded);
```

I connect to the hub connection like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import * as signalR from '@microsoft/signalr';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignalRService {
  SIGNALR_URL = environment.signalRBaseUrl;

  public hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;
  public startConnection = () => {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(this.SIGNALR_URL + '/sourceControlHub')
      .build();

    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log('Connection started'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: ', err));
  };

  public addProgressReportingListener() {
    this.hubConnection.on(
      'SendProgressReportMessage',
      (snapshotId, toUpload, uploaded) => {
        console.log(
          'reporting the data: ' +
            snapshotId +
            ' ' +
            uploaded +
            ' of ' +
            toUpload
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

And initiate it in my component:

```
    this.signalRService.startConnection();
    this.signalRService.addProgressReportingListener();
```

I tried with an older version of @aspnet/signalr which didn't work either. I am currently using latest version of @microsoft/signalr in the Angular project.

Edit: Moved the last paragraph, where I explained the issue, to the top of the post.

Comment: Try adding logging to the client-side and seeing if there are any hints there.
https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-5.0#error-handling-and-logging

Comment: Hey Brennan, thank you for the response :) I added logging on the client side, the connection gets established, and I monitored it for a while, but nothing else was logged after the connection had been established to the hub. I can see in Seq that it still sends out the messages.

Comment: Bump :) Still looking for advise on this matter